# Spring Integration Tests - idiomatic way of overriding beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

how can I override beans in Spring (Boot) Integration Tests the idiomatic way?

Up until now I had source configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfiguration {
  @Bean
  CarsRepository carsRepository() {
    // return some real sql db
  }
}
```

And tests like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationISpec extends Specification {
  @Configuration
  @Import(Application.class)
  static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    CarsRepository testsCarsRepository() {
      // return some in-memory repository
    }
  }

  def "it can do stuff with cars"() {
    // do some REST requests to application and verify it works
    // there is no need to make real calls to real DB
  }
}
```

First thing is that test bean `testsCarsRepository` method must differ than original one (which is not obvious, and there is no warning/error about it).
But the final question is: what is the idiomatic way of overriding beans with Spring in integration tests?

When I posted my WTF about method name on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/snicoll/status/921452796985118723) - [Stephane Nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/stephane-nicoll) said the `@Primary` is not intended to be used for overriding beans in tests.

So what is the preferred way of that?

Comment: `@MockBean` looks a good option.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I've edited post, so it says more about the use case. I dont want to mock my bean. Instead of that I just want to replace it with some other implementation for tests only. Imagine I want to run Spring integration tests (so all beans graph is loaded) but I want to replace some boundary beans (like DB, external services, or sth) with in-memory implementations

Comment: What you're referring to is why we've created `MockBean` for. If you want to run with in-memory database, we have support for that too (`@AutoconfigureTestDatabase`). Overriding a bean without the use of profile requires ordering and using the same bean name so it's a bit fragile. So I'd look at those options before rejecting them.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll thanks for the input. So probably `@Profile` & `@Primary` is the way to go for me. I want to replace application bean with a test bean. It doesnt have to be a db related. It can has some configuration options, or sth like that. And I dont want to mock it. I just want to use different implementation for tests. Thanks for contribution!

Comment: You don't need `@Primary`. The accepted answer looks somewhat good to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@Profile` together with `@ActiveProfile` annotation to separate you test and production configurations. For example change you test config to:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CarsISpec extends Specification {
    @Configuration
    @Import(Application.class)
    @Profile("test")
    static class TestConfig {
       @Bean
       CarsRepository testsCarsRepository() {
       // return some in-memory repository
       }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to mark you production configuration `ApplicationConfiguration` with `@Profile("!test")`.

Also Spring Boot provides numerous tools for testing (e.g. `@DataJpaTest` with embedded database, `@MockBean` for mocking beans in context and etc.) [Link to doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that approach but was confused with Stepahne Nicoll answer on my tweet, so that is why I asked. Nevertheless thanks for the input!

Comment: You don't need all that code btw. If you have just `@TestConfiguration` for your `TestConfig` it will work. The ActiveProfiles will disable the "production" service and the extra config will be applied on top on the default behaviour (basically detecting the `Application` class). Can you edit your answer if you agree?

Comment: Thank you for reply! To be honest I do not understand how to apply `@TestConfiguration` correctly to this piece of code. Can I ask you to post your own answer with your approach? Including the reason of why `@ActiveProfiles` is not the best choice. I'm sure it will we helpful for me and for author of question.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key weakness of this approach is the requirement to add `@Profile("!test")` to application bean. I want my tests to selectively replace any application bean one-by-one, not all of them at the same time in the same test... This is impossible with this approach because as soon as I add `@Profile("!test")` to my bean, all my tests will require another "mock bean" instead of this bean and application context will not start until I provide some implementation of the bean (because other application's beans can depend on it).